# How to disable module tun on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04

I use Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS x86_64.

`lsmod | grep tun` prints no output but

`modprobe -r tun` yields `FATAL: Module tun in builtin`

How to disable module `tun` on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Comment: What do you mean with "disable module tun"?
Which kernel do you run? "uname -a"

Comment: Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

The tun feature is build static into the ubuntu kernel, so you can't remove it.